# Usable output from numpy.where() function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm calling a function in a python script which I want to return a set of indices. Basically I want to strip the `(array([index1]),array([index2]))` return from numpy.where() so I just have  `([index1],[index2])`.

I've tried converting to a string and using `arr.strip('array')` but that didn't work.

I guess I should clear some things up. I want the function to return a value and then the two indices as so `[val, index1, index2]`

As it is, the return looks more like this: `[val, (array([index1]), array([index2]))]`

Basically I search through two arrays, Lat and Lon, to see where they have the same indexes that each one meets its own requirement for. Then I calculate the distance between those points and a given point and append it on to a list.

```
    for i in range(len(smalllat)):
            temp = [smalllat[i], smalllon[i]]
            loc = N.where((lat==smalllat[i]) & (lon==smalllon[i]))
            smallset.append([dist_calc.distance(temp, [lat1, lon1]), loc])
```

I then sort the list by the first value( distance) and return the first four arrays.

```
    dset = sorted(smallset)
    return dset[:4]
```

which gives me something of the form:

```
[[3.3883810544766138, (array([72]), array([232]))], 
 [25.248157869075957, (array([72]), array([231]))],
 [34.31977394077627, (array([71]), array([232]))], 
 [42.651294795468786, (array([71]), array([233]))]]
```

I want to store them in a `(x, 4, 3)` numpy array, where x is the number of times I run the function.

The desired output would be something like:

```
[[[3.3883810544766138, 72, 232], 
 [25.248157869075957, 72, 231],
 [34.31977394077627, 71, 232], 
 [42.651294795468786, 71, 233]],
 ...,
 [[3.3883810544766138, 72, 232], 
 [25.248157869075957, 72, 231],
 [34.31977394077627, 71, 232], 
 [42.651294795468786, 71, 233]]]
```

Feel free to ask questions.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update**

I got the output I wanted by changing the function to:

```
    for i in range(len(smalllat)):
            temp = [smalllat[i], smalllon[i]]
            loc = N.where((lat==smalllat[i]) & (lon==smalllon[i]))
            loc = [map(int, x) for x in loc]
            loc1 = loc[0]
            loc2 = loc[1]
            smallset.append([dist_calc.distance(temp, [lat1, lon1]), loc1[0], loc2[0]])
```

I'm sure there's a better way though.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you're asking. "Usable" in what sense? What are you trying to do? The output of `where` is quite usable for [fancy indexing](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-3f4d28139e045a442f78c5218c379af64c2c8c9e).

Comment: Usable wasn't the right word, I just want the guts of the returned arrays.

Comment: A more concrete example of the array you're searching, and the expected and actual output would be helpful.

Comment: Are `smalllat` and `smalllon` one or two-dimensional?